# Why is there no TeX.SX community ad on Academia.SX?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Visiting the [2015 community ads on Academia.SX](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1478), I can see that TeX.SX does not have any advertisements on the site. Why does not TeX.SX have an ad there?

I always think that users who have questions about topics like publications, writing styles, journal paper submission, citations, etc. at Academia.SX are the most relevant users to see an advertisement about TeX and LaTeX.

Comment: Surely this is a question for the academia site, not for us? (Moreover, TeX is used only in some parts of academia so they might have a good reason for this.)

Comment: @JosephWright I thought that the users of TeX.SX who are users of Academia.SX too, should propose an ad for it. As there was no ad for TeX there, I thought that this site has a policy to not promote itself in Academia. How should I find the advertisement image for TeX.SX? I want to propose it on the 2015 community ads on Academia.

Comment: Ah good ol' days :P http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2838/sx-promotion-ad-help-request-question

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent Nice idea. I don't have a picture to add, if you have one, you can add it there, it'll very likely get enough upvotes soon :)

Comment: @yo' Should the image be designed so professionally?